How to get health API data of android user from google
how can I get details of user using health care app in android
I have created one Project into Google Cloud Console and have authorized with OAuth 2.O authentication and get client Id and client secret Key. Also in OAuth 2.0 Playground have done with one API for get user's details but getting Data Source null. I want to have particular user's health care data

Hello, Are you using any kind of fitness watch to get data..?, if yes then it's depend on watch company, Mostly company do not expose health care data to user.
